# How do I change/refresh the maven project.basedir property?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I had my maven project folder B (with the pom)  in another folder A. A is the root folder of the associated git repository, however, and all that was in it was the maven project folder B. I had some problems with relative paths because of this and now I moved every file and directory in B to A. The problem I have now is that the basedir property didn't change. Maven can compile everything correctly, but at runtime I get an error because in the pom.xml I have specified the path to a resource using `${project.basedir}`. At runtime I see that this expands to a path that still contains the old, now deleted folder B. How do I fix this? I need some way of updating the project.basedir property, but I don't know where/how its value is determined.

Project structure initially:

```
A
└── B
    ├── ...
    └── pom.xml
```

Project structure now:

```
A
├── ...
└── pom.xml
```

Value of `${project.basedir}` initially: `.../A/B`

Value of `${project.basedir}` now: `.../A/B` (still)

But I need value of `${project.basedir}` to be: `.../A` only

This is because I now need `${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/myResource` to expand to `.../A/src/main/resources/myResource` instead of `.../A/B/src/main/resources/myResource` (which gives me a FileNotFound Error at the moment).

Best and appreciate answers :)

Comment: Can you draw a picture of that or even better show an example project on github or alike? Unfortunately I don't understand your problem... ?

Comment: @khmarbaise hey. I elaborated and hope my problem is understandable now.

Comment: Why do you need to access a resource outside of a maven project (pom.xml) java code location? And why do you need to access it via `${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/..` which  I don't understand. If you are trying to access it via `File` that  is simply wrong. You should check go via `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myResources/file.x")`... ?

Comment: Look at the plugin pom definition here https://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html

Comment: @khmarbaise I used this cxf plugin to generate a web service client. Apache recommends putting the .wsdl files (which are used as input to generate the java files) in the resources folder and referring to them in the pom like I have done. "recommend" meaning that's what they've done in the sample code.

Comment: @khmarbaise I just found out that this error is from somewhere else!!!!! Wouldn't have been able to find it without being able to bounce off you so thanks a lot!! Basically this issue is in my java code where I have a hardcoded path to the .wsdl file. This hardcoded path was still had B in the path.

Comment: So is the basedir property actually correct and always recomputed by maven before compiling (by looking at where the pom file is)?

Comment: The referenced example is how it could be configured but it shouldn't be because Maven is based on convention over configuration paradigm...

Comment: Why is getClass() necessary to call a function that gets the resource from the conventional place. I find this getClass() approach very ugly.

Comment: How you would make the access to the resources?

Comment: There is no way to change `project.basedir`, it is a Maven internal property that points to a directory, where `pom.xml` located. 

As for `${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/myResource` path - it should work and is a valid path, assuming you have `myResource` folder in your `resources`.